# Keep edges seperated

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I have created the following diagram using ELK.

[image: ELK Diagram]

Now I'm trying to use cytoscape.js with cytoscape.js-elk to generate the same routing. However I cannot get the edges the same was with ELK.

I keep getting the following:
[image: cytoscape.js-elk overlapping edges]

What do I need to do to get the same edge route as ELK generates? I have tried changing the ELK options, but I don't think this is caused by elk, I think this is caused by cytoscape.

My style

```js
        const style = [ // the stylesheet for the graph
            {
                selector: 'node',
                style: {
                    shape: 'rectangle',
                    label: 'data(id)',
                    'font-size': '0.5em',
                }
            },
            {
                selector: 'edge',
                style: {
                    'width': 1,
                    'curve-style': 'taxi',
                    'line-color': '#ccc',
                    label: 'data(id)',
                    'font-size': '0.5em',
                    'color': 'blue',
                    'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
                    'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
                }
            }
        ];
```

Settings

```
        cytoscape.use(elk);

        var cy = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById('cy'),
            style: style,
            layout: { name: 'elk' }
        });
```

Nodes & Edges

```
        var nodes = cy.add([
            { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n1'} },
            { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n2'} },
            { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n4'} },
            { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n9'} },
            { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n10' } },
            { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n555'} },
            { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n556'} },
            { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n557'} },
        ])

        var edges = cy.add([
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e3', source: 'n1', target: 'n4' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e19', source: 'n1', target: 'n9' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e12', source: 'n2', target: 'n1' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e842', source: 'n2', target: 'n9' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e15', source: 'n2', target: 'n10' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e10', source: 'n4', target: 'n2' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e908', source: 'n4', target: 'n4' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e843', source: 'n4', target: 'n9' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e11', source: 'n4', target: 'n10' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e905', source: 'n4', target: 'n555' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e862', source: 'n4', target: 'n557' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e802', source: 'n9', target: 'n1' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e7', source: 'n10', target: 'n2' } },
            { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e8', source: 'n10', target: 'n4' } },
        ]);
```

Options

```
            var options = {
            name: "elk",
            nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true, // Boolean which changes whether label dimensions are included when calculating node dimensions
            fit: true, // Whether to fit
            padding: 20, // Padding on fit
            animate: false, // Whether to transition the node positions
            animateFilter: function (node, i) { return true; }, // Whether to animate specific nodes when animation is on; non-animated nodes immediately go to their final positions
            animationDuration: 500, // Duration of animation in ms if enabled
            animationEasing: undefined, // Easing of animation if enabled
            transform: function (node, pos) { return pos; }, // A function that applies a transform to the final node position
            ready: undefined, // Callback on layoutready
            stop: undefined, // Callback on layoutstop
            elk: {
                'algorithm': 'layered',
                'layered.mergeEdges': 'false',
                'layered.mergeHierarchyEdges': 'false',
                'crossingMinimization.semiInteractive': true,
                'nodePlacement.strategy': 'NETWORK_SIMPLEX',
                'layered.wrapping.additionalEdgeSpacing': 50,
                'spacing.nodeNode': 50,
                'spacing.nodeNodeBetweenLayers': 25,
                'spacing.edgeNode': 25,
                'spacing.edgeNodeBetweenLayers': 20,
                'spacing.edgeEdge': 20,
                'spacing.edgeEdgeBetweenLayers': 15,
                // All options are available at http://www.eclipse.org/elk/reference.html
                // 'org.eclipse.elk.' can be dropped from the Identifier
                // Or look at demo-demo.js for an example.
                // Enums use the name of the enum e.g.
                // 'searchOrder': 'DFS'
                //
                // The main field to set is `algorithm`, which controls which particular
                // layout algorithm is used.
            },
            priority: function (edge) { return null; }, // Edges with a non-nil value are skipped when geedy edge cycle breaking is enabled
        };

        cy.layout(options).run();
```

Comment: it seems like they are the same but the edges are overlapping.

Comment: Taxi edges, as is stated [here](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/taxi-edges), are designed to **bundle** edges in a hierarchy, they "are appropriate for trees and DAGs that are laid out in a hierarchical manner". Your result is unpleasant but normal, that's how taxi edges work.

Comment: @StephanT. Is there a type of edge that will follow the same route as in elk?

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem. Another you will encounter is that the lines will go through the nodes, there is no effort to route around them. For me this has rendered taxi useless, even though I much prefer it's appearance. I am not aware of any line drawing algorithm in cytoscape that fixes either of these issues.

My reluctant conclusion is that I need to switch platforms, and transfer entirely to Sprotty and ELK (which was probably used to draw your reference graph).

https://rtsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/elklive/examples.html?e=general%2FmixingDirection
https://www.typefox.io/blog/sprotty-a-web-based-diagramming-framework

Examples with Sprotty show lines actually routing around nodes, and junction points on nodes to show where overlapping lines actually join. Additionally it uses SVGs rather than a raster-render system. This may result in a crisper font, but also has the advantage of searchable text in your diagram (if you care about that).

I have yet to take the plunge on yet another framework, but it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing similar kind of problem where my edges are overlapping to each other. To overcome  this problem you can use `curve-style: straight;`.[image: Sample image]

[Edges type demo](https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/edge-types/)